# Python dataframe count the values in a row and add status to the another row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Have a df with values

```
name    subject  

mark     M         
mark     S
mark     P
mark     SS
staurt   M
cuban    S
cuban    P
```

if a usercount in name is present more once in name column then present status should be YES , if it's only once then status present status should be NO

```
name    subject   present status

mark     M          YES
mark     S          YES
mark     P          YES
mark     SS         YES
staurt   M          No
cuban    S          YES
cuban    P          YES
```

tried this:

df['present status'] = np.where(df['name'] == df['name'].shift(), 'YES', 'NO')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
df['present status'] = np.where(df['name'].duplicated(keep=False), 'YES', 'NO')
print (df)
     name subject present status
0    mark       M            YES
1    mark       S            YES
2    mark       P            YES
3    mark      SS            YES
4  staurt       M             NO
5   cuban       S            YES
6   cuban       P            YES
```